# SQL: Grouping data with sub-query

Tags: sql, sqlite

Hoping someone can help me with this query.

If I have a sample table:

```
orderId | itemId | quantity | created
123456  | 1      | 100      | 1478822402
123457  | 1      | 5        | 1478736001
123458  | 2      | 10       | 1478736001
123459  | 2      | 40       | 1478822402
```

I am trying to get a result set which gives me the sum of the quantities of items sold today and yesterday - grouped by item. For example:

```
item    | numSoldToday   | numSoldYesterday
1       | 100            | 5
2       | 40             | 10
```

Ignoring the hard coded timestamps for testing purposes, I can do this for just items sold today using:

```
SELECT item, sum(quantity) as numSoldToday FROM orders
WHERE created >= 1478822400 AND created <= 1478908799
GROUP by item
```

And I can do do this for just ONE item sold today vs. yesterday using a subquery:

```
SELECT sum(quantity) as numSoldToday, 
(SELECT (sum(quantity) FROM orders WHERE created >= 1478736000 AND created <= 1478822399 AND item = 1) as numSoldYesterday
FROM orders
WHERE created >= 1478822400 AND created <= 1478908799 AND item = 1
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to combine the two - a grouped result set of each item with the number sold today vs. yesterday without using the client side programming language to get a list of items and loop through each one which seems a bit inefficient.

I tried putting a GROUP BY in the subquery but this just gave me an error and I can't think of the best way to proceed with doing this purely with SQL.

Any ideas welcome!
Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in an aggregated case statement rather than subqueries, something like this;

```
SELECT
o.item
,SUM(CASE WHEN o.created >= 1478822400 AND o.created <= 1478908799 THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) numSoldToday
,SUM(CASE WHEN o.created >= 1478736000 AND o.created <= 1478822399 THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) numSoldYesterday
FROM orders o
GROUP BY o.item
```

Comment: i think the op is looking to do this for all the dates.

Comment: That's not how I read it: "But I can't seem to figure out how to combine the two - a grouped result set of each item with the number sold today vs. yesterday". I don't recognise that date format or i'd suggest something using getdate() too

Comment: I'm not looking for all the dates - each group of timestamps represents "today" (00.00-23.59) and "yesterday" (same). I just need the number that fit into each category.

Comment: Just tested Rich's solution - works great and I need to read up on these aggregated expressions - thanks!